# Trying to open a OneDrive directory file path using a batch file

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, batch-file, path, onedrive

I am attempting to open a OneDrive file path whose location is synced locally to my computer using a batch file, but after several trial and errors, I'm not able to determine what I'm doing wrong. So far I've seen other post a "fix" by using the "DIR" syntax, but my desired goal isn't to just show me what files are in my OneDrive path, but to open the path in file explorer. So far I have tried the following:

```
start C:\Users\my_name\OneDrive - CompanyName\desired_folder

start C:\Users\my_name\"OneDrive - CompanyName"\desired_folder

start "C:\Users\my_name\OneDrive - CompanyName\desired_folder"

start C:\Users\my_name\%OneDrive - CompanyName%\desired_folder

start C:\Users\my_name\"%OneDrive - CompanyName%"\desired_folder
```

I'm at a total loss here and keep getting the same "Windows cannot find file path" error. Can anyone tell me how to simply open a file path associated with OneDrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with paths with spaces, you escape the entire path with quotes.

So the first step you do is use explorer to navigate to the path you want to open in your script. You then click next to the path so it becomes text, and you can see the entire path. Copy this path to the clipboard.

Now head over to your script and paste it down.

Add quotes on either side. If you prepend `start` to it, you basically say: I want to open this file with the associated program. Given that no filename is specified, a new command prompt opens instead or throws an error. This is not what you want.

So instead of using `start "full path"`, you use `explorer "full path"`.

So in your case this becomes:

```
explorer "C:\Users\my_name\OneDrive - CompanyName\desired_folder"
```

Comment: I can't believe that worked. I've been wracking my brain about this for a week since I started trying to teach myself how to write batch files. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome. :) Glad I could help.